# "Best Fit" behavior for Godot Container

Tags: 2d, godot

I'm looking for a Container or Control that can automatically resize its contents to the "Best Fit". Meaning the container's contents should fill as much available space as they can without going outside the borders, but maintain their aspect ratio. An example would look like the green box in this image:

[image]

I can of course code this behavior on a Node2D by having it recalculate scale whenever there's a change, but I was hoping to figure out the right way to pull this off with Controls. This seems like a common enough use case that it should be built-in, but no combination I've tried of controls and size flags behaves like this. What else should I try?

Comment: You seem to have a requirement you are not mentioning: that the arrangement must be a rectangle. Which would mean we need a factorization of the number of elements. And also that if the number is a prime, you get only one row or column. Even with that there is a requirement that is unclear: do you prefer columns or rows? In the example we see cases where the arrangement has more rows and where it has more columns. Anyway, once we have the requirement clear I think an `AspectRatioContainer` with a `GridContainer` plus some script to set them based on the number of children will work.

Comment: @Theraot Irrelevant: the number of rows and columns are user-defined. I have the grid already made, I just need a Container that will take that grid then resize its contents to fit the container without changing the aspect ratio of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: Godot does not have a `Control` that does what you want out of the box at the time of writing.

*The rest of this answer is a possible approach to do it with the `Control`s that Godot has right now.*

---

Since you already have the grid. Then you can archive what you want with the help of a `AspectRatioContainer`.

Keep in mind that the `AspectRatioContainer` does not preserve the aspect ratio the child had originally, instead it imposes one. Thus, you need to have it impose the correct aspect ratio for the grid.

Set the `AspectRatioContainer` layout to "Full Rect", of course.

---

I'll be assuming your scene is setup like this:

```
AspectRatioContainer
└ GridContainer.
  ├ Control1
  ├ …
  └ ControlN
```

With the `GridContainer`, the number of `columns` is one of its properties. We can compute the number of `rows` by dividing the number of children over the `columns`. With `rows` and `columns` we compute the aspect ratio. Like this:

```
    var columns := float(grid_container.columns)
    var rows := ceil(grid_container.get_child_count() / columns)
    ratio = columns / rows
```

Notice I'm having `columns` as a `float`. I don't need to. I might have done it like this instead:

```
    var columns := grid_container.columns
    var rows := ceil(float(grid_container.get_child_count()) / columns)
    ratio = columns / rows
```

The point is that the divisions are not integer division. Because we need a `float` for `ratio`.

---

Since the `AspectRatioContainer` will be imposing the correct aspect ratio, each `Control` child  of the `GridContainer` will have an square available for them.

To make them use them, set the "Expand" flag on `size_flags_horizontal` and `size_flags_vertical` of the children `Control`s of the `GridContainer` so they grow and fill the space. Otherwise they will remain shrunk to their minimum size.

---

Now, when do we execute the code I have shown above? One option is to do it on ready:

```
extends AspectRatioContainer

onready var grid_container: GridContainer = $GridContainer

func _ready() -> void:
    var columns := float(grid_container.columns)
    var rows := ceil(grid_container.get_child_count() / columns)
    ratio = columns / rows
    property_list_changed_notify()
```

But that will run only once, and thus won't react to changing the children of the `GridContainer`.

Instead I will move that code to another method which I'll call `fix_ratio`, so you can easily call it whenever the grid changes.

The code could be like this:

```
extends AspectRatioContainer

onready var grid_container: GridContainer = $GridContainer

func fix_ratio() -> void:
    var columns := float(grid_container.columns)
    var rows := ceil(grid_container.get_child_count() / columns)
    ratio = columns / rows
```

In fact, you can go ahead and connect the `"sort_children"` signal of the `GridContainer` to the `fix_ratio` in the editor.

Or, since we are here, let us do it from code:

```
extends AspectRatioContainer

onready var grid_container: GridContainer = $GridContainer

func _ready() -> void:
    if not grid_container.is_connected("sort_children", self, "fix_ratio"):
        # warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
        grid_container.connect("sort_children", self, "fix_ratio")

func fix_ratio() -> void:
    var columns := float(grid_container.columns)
    var rows := ceil(grid_container.get_child_count() / columns)
    ratio = columns / rows
```

If you want the behavior to happen in the editor, you can make it a `tool` script by adding the `tool` keyword as first line. I'll also call `property_list_changed_notify()` so Godot updates the inspector right away.

Note: If you added the `tool` keyword to an script, you might need to close and open again the scene in the editor for the script to start executing in the editor.

```
tool
extends AspectRatioContainer

onready var grid_container: GridContainer = $GridContainer

func _ready() -> void:
    if not grid_container.is_connected("sort_children", self, "fix_ratio"):
        # warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
        grid_container.connect("sort_children", self, "fix_ratio")

func fix_ratio() -> void:
    var columns := float(grid_container.columns)
    var rows := ceil(grid_container.get_child_count() / columns)
    ratio = columns / rows
    property_list_changed_notify()
```

---

As I said, I've been assuming you have a `GridContainer`, but you might not. Whatever you have, you need to expose some property or properties the script in the `AspectRatioContainer` can read to figure out the aspect ratio to use and use it in a similar fashion to what I have shown above.

Comment: I should have been more clear: I already wrote behavior to recalculate the ratio and scale on change (much like you've done) but does Godot seriously not have a node that achieves the effect for you? I can think of so many use cases where you'd want something with a fixed ratio to fill as much space as possible without stretching (video playback as an example) and I'd be shocked if it's not already handled.

Comment: @4444 You are welcome to be shocked. For example, `AspectRatioContainer` was added in Godot 3.3 (2021), and the `HFlowContainer` and `VFlowContainer` in Godot 3.5 (2022). The cases I can think of are a. you know the aspect ratio before hand, b. the aspect ratio you want to keep is based on the container not the contents, or c. it is an image. If you can think of scenarios that need to recalculate based on a child `Control`, please submit a proposal: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues or bring it to discussion: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions

Comment: Feel free to add that as a separate answer - something along the lines of "It doesn't exist yet." - and I'll mark it as accepted. Your existing answer is useful, but if what you're saying is true... then the true answer is that Godot doesn't have a control for the job.

Comment: @4444 I do not believe that makes a good answer on its own. But I'll edit the answer. Edit: Done.